# Call Javascript function after Salesforce NavigationMixin.Navigate

Tags: javascript, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

The Salesforce NavigationMixin.Navigate method allows opening a pop up edit window on a custom Lightning Page.

How do I refresh the custom page after the Save button is pressed on the Edit modal?  I see the generateUrl method generates a promise but the Navigate method I don't see anything.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_navigate_default